# How to change shortcuts in 2.8

Tags: customization

I'm new to Blender, I've been using it only for a couple of days. I first downloaded 2.79 and change some of the shortcuts. I've just discovered 2.8 and I want to change them aswell. However this is what shows up if I try to enter user preferences. Isn't it possible to change it yet?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Keymap]

Just got to the Keymap Tab, that is where the settings are now.

Comment: thanks! I feel such a noobie haha

Comment: Believe me, I know how you feel. ^^